# Unusual Problem with Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am running ghci from Terminal.

In my source file, I defined

```
factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial n = product [1 .. n]
```

When I run this, I get the result

```
factorial 13 = 1932053504

product [1 .. 13] = 6227020800
```

For any number less than 13, the result is correct. However, for any number greater than or equal to 12, the two result do not agree.

Also if I define this function recursive :

```
factorial' :: Int -> Int
factorial' 0 = 1
factorial' (n + 1) = (n + 1) * factorial' n
```

I still get

```
factorial' 13 = 1932053504
```

If you understand what is occurring here, it would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: By the way, note that when Haskell needs a concrete type for an expression that could be polymorphic, it uses a defaulting system that, among other things, will choose `Integer` for any integral numeric type. So that's why `product [1..13]` has a different type.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the documentation for `Int`: `A fixed-precision integer type with at least the range [-2^29 .. 2^29-1]`.  Your `factorial` function is typed to use a an `Int`, which is overflowing.  Now, if we check out the type of the second answer (from simply using `product` in GHCi), we see that it is of type `Integer`:

```
Prelude> let a = product [1 .. 13]
Prelude> :t a
a :: Integer
```

`Integer` is unbounded, and so is able to hold such a large number without overflowing.

Answer (score 6):

You have the wrong types: `Int` wraps around somewhere (probably 2^31), you need `Integer` for unlimited integer values:

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = product [1 .. n]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the problem.

Comment: it's only guaranteed to support up to 2^29-1